# How to log large requests as files?

Tags: python, logging

I am using a Flask app to solve vehicle routing problems. It receives large requests (around 5MB each) that I would like to log outside of the usual logging messages (e.g. `app.logger.info(..)`) because they just render the logs unreadable.

My idea is to save the last *n* requests as json files with timestamps in a separate folder. I am about to write my own function to do this. I am wondering if you have used this type of setup before and how you implemented it. I couldn't find anything in Python's module `logging` to do this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using the logger module to save large json files, especially if you also want them formatted for human consumption.

I actually had the same problem as you in the past, and solved it writing the following function:

```
def json_to_file(file_to_write, json_to_dump):
    max_files = 10
    file_list = sorted(glob.glob("your pattern here"))
    if len(file_list) > max_files:
        os.remove(file_list[0])

    with open(file_to_write, "w+") as my_file:
        json.dump(json_to_dump, my_file, indent=4)
```

You could format the file_to_write variable to be a unix or utc timestamp - that's what I do anyway.

Edit: added the "max n files" part. **Just make sure you're using the right pattern with glob!**

Comment: Ok. But i also have to make sure that the function deletes the oldest request file if there are already *n* requests saved.

Comment: @LeeviL I expanded the answer.

Comment: There are several ways why just the half of a file could be written. A lot of more then KeyboardInterrupt. I think this is an answer to a different question. If the one asking the question is new, this could confuse him.

Comment: You're right. I removed the KeyboardInterrupt part  since it wasn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should ignore the logging module in this case.

Take a directory and create the files in this directory.

You can use the current datetime for the file_name.

It has a paranoid way of creating a unique name:

```
import datetime
import os
import random

request_dir = '/tmp'
content =':-)'
now = datetime.datetime.now()
file_name = '%s_%s_%s.json' % (now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S'), '%06d' % now.microsecond,
                          random.randint(100000000, 999999999))
with open(os.path.join(request_dir, file_name), 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(content)
```

The part "deleting old entries in the directory" is left undone. This is not difficult since the file names can be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python logger, you can specify where it writes using `FileHandler` like this:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=os.path.join(path_to_log_directory, log_filename))
fh.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
```

Comment: I want to separate the usual logging messages from large request data. Each request (about 5MB) should be saved in a separate file. Your solution still saves everything in a single file.

Comment: You would have to change it everytime. But this really seems like a workaround. It seems better to write it yourself